# Get average of fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

In this SQL statement:

```
select (ISNULL(Tbl1.Bromod,0) + ISNULL(Tbl1.Bromoform,0) +  
   ISNULL(Tbl1.Chlor,0)  + ISNULL(Tbl1.Dibromoc,0)) / 4 ) 
   from TblTruck
```

I'd like to dynamically change the value that is 4 currently to be the number of values that are NOT `NULL`.

What I am trying to do is to get the average ignoring NULL entries.

Say if `Bromod` is `NULL` and the others are not `BULL`, I would then divide by 3, as 3 actually have values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select (
    ISNULL(Tbl1.Bromod,0) + ISNULL(Tbl1.Bromoform,0) +  ISNULL(Tbl1.Chlor,0)  + ISNULL(Tbl1.Dibromoc,0)
)
/ ISNULL(
    NULLIF(
        CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(BIT,ISNULL(Tbl1.Bromod,0))) + CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(BIT,ISNULL(Tbl1.Bromoform,0))) +  CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(BIT,ISNULL(Tbl1.Chlor,0)))  + CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(BIT,ISNULL(Tbl1.Dibromoc,0)))
        ,0
    )
        ,1
    )
from TblTruck Tbl1
```

So,neat trick, all #s other than zero convert as a true when cast as a bit. So, NULLs and 0's become zero and all other values become 1. Sum together and that gives you what you are looking for. This solution also handles a divide by zero issue that would arise if all values were null/zero.

Comment: Hello I know you made some tweaks Which one is the final version

Comment: The most recent @NatePet

Comment: So it is the one that has: ISNULL(
    NULLIF(
        CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(BIT,ISNULL(Tbl1.Bromod,0))) ... Correct?

Comment: Yes, it is the one currently displayed as an answer.